# Intersection of a surface and a curve in $\mathbb{P}^n$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose $X$ is a smooth projective surface of general type of degree $d$ in $\mathbb{P}^n$. Is it possible to find a curve of degree $k$ which intersects $X$ in $dk$ points ?

Comment: Certainly if your surface is contained in some $\mathbb{P}^3\subset \mathbb{P}^n$.

Comment: I am sorry. I meant for a non-degenerated  surface in $\mathbb{P}^n$.

Comment: You are asking for some $k$ or for all $k$?

Comment: I am asking for all $k$. But is it true for some $k$? If yes, then can we say something about $k$?

Answer (score 4):

The answer is *no* for all $k$, in fact, there are already counterexamples for $k=1$.

For instance, there exist smooth, non-degenerate surfaces $X \subset \mathbb{P}^6$ such that every line intersect them in at most two points, see

S. Di Rocco, K. Ranestad: [On surfaces in $\mathbb{P}^{6}$ with no trisecant lines](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02384319), *Ark. Mat*. **38**, No. 2 (2000), 231-261 . [ZBL1035.14011](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1035.14011).

Comment: Is it true for some $k$ ?

Comment: I do not know off the top of my head.  I should think about it.